# Override series names in Dygraphs legend

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have control over the axes labels using *xlabel* and *ylabel*.  How can I substitute series names in the legend?  I have searched the options and see no opportunity.

Comment: I wound up creating a custom div for the legend, and using highlightCallback() and unhighlightCallback() to feed it selection info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to build dygraphs from `HEAD`, you could use the new [`labelFormatter` option](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/683). It lets you construct whatever HTML you like.